# Expiration Session in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

plz how can i know if the session is expired or not ? what function can i use to get that ? im using zend framework 2 and session container for storing data from authentification.

```
if ($request->isPost()) 
{       

            $mySession = new Container('mySession');
            $mySession->pseudo = $pseudo;
            $mySession->login = $name;
            $mySession->password = $password;
            $mySession->profil = $droit      
            $mySession->id = $id;   
}
```

Comment: ZF will create sessions for you on demand, you don't normally need to worry about whether they exist or not.

Comment: i want to get the expiration time for the session , i guess it should be possible !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the expiration time of the cookie, you can use

```
$mySession->getManager()->getConfig()->getCookieLifetime();
```

You can also check if a key exists with

```
$mySession->offsetExists('your_key');
```